# disable some buttons TinyMCE

Tags: javascript, tinymce, wysiwyg

Can I somehow by running a javacript command disable some buttons..

Not on the `TinyMCE.init`, as I need to disable some of the buttons when a special event is happening.

I have tried `cm.setDisabled(1);` but that makes all buttons disabled.

Any ideas if there is a call for that?
Or should I try make a javascript function which i can call whenever to disable/re-enable a button again?

Comment: tinymce seems to have quite good documentation.
http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/API3:tinymce.api.3.x

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try to follow this [fiddle..](http://fiddle.tinymce.com/O6caab/1)

```
Here Bold and Save buttons get disabled on clicking Disable button
and enabled on clicking Enable button.

Buttons are at the bottom of the page
```

For disabling a specific button you need id of that button which is your
    divId_buttonName like

```
tinyMCE.activeEditor.controlManager.get('disable_save').setDisabled(true) ;
```

In order to enable it again

```
tinyMCE.activeEditor.controlManager.get('disable_save').setDisabled(false) ;
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Doesn't work in TinyMCE 4 since the controlManager has been removed. More information here: http://www.tinymce.com/forum/viewtopic.php?id=31340